# FastAPI API-key Unittesting

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi

I've seen many people using API-key in FASTAPI with down below function.

```
async def get_api_key(api_key_header: str = Security(api_key_header)):
    if api_key_header == config_env["API_KEY"]:
        return api_key_heade
    else:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN, detail="Could not validate API KEY"
        )
```

And my question is why have to make get_api_key async, cuz there's no await in the function. What's the purpose and how it works and the difference using def.
And my second question is how should i unittest this function without using testing endpoint. i want to directly test this code how should i do since there's no await in this function. The api_key_header returned by get_api_key function will always be coroutine object.